# Ruby conditional: display nothing

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

What's the best way to explicitly display nothing in a div if a conditional is met? For example:

```
<% if this_condition.is_met %>
  <!-- display nothing here -->
<% elsif that_condition.is_met %>
  <p>This is supposed to be visible.</p>
<% end %>
```

Further clarification: There are several conditions. Meeting one of the conditions should hide the content in the div.

Comment: are you talking about *comment* out ? If you don't want to display, why checking conditions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "explicitly display nothing"? You need to explain it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit Nope. I'm talking about the situation where a user doesn't meet a condition and therefore can't see a certain snippet of content.

Comment: I think you told, if condition met, *not to show*. May be I am reading posted code that way.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
<% if !this_condition.is_met && that_condition.is_met %>
  <p>This is supposed to be visible.</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use it like:

```
<% if !this_condition.is_met && that_condition.is_met %>
   <p>This is supposed to be visible.</p>
<% end %>
```

why do you need else.

Comment: After you edited it, it is not different from BroiSatse's code. No need of a duplicate answer.

Comment: @sawa yes actually I wanted to write this only, previous on was in hurry, by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor to try and encapsulate the logic in a single method like:

`def show_content?
  !this_condition.is_met && that_condition.is_met
end`

This will keep your view as simple as possible. Code that is easier to read, is easier to maintain.

`<%= content_tag(:p, "This is supposed to be visible.") if show_content? %>`

Also `show_content?` would be much easier to test in isolation.